# How to print 1st column of the rows to next line untill that rows has some string in the first column

Tags: text-processing

Example i have file data like below.

```
A  aaa
"  bbb
"  ccc
B  ddd
"  eee
C  fff
```

I am looking for

```
A aaa
A bbb
A ccc
B ddd
B eee
C fff
```

Comment: What have you tried?  How did it not work as expected or intended?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

A fairly simple ask for `awk`:

```
$ cat inputfile
A  aaa
"  bbb
"  ccc
B  ddd
"  eee
C  fff
$ awk -f '$1 != "\"" { leader=$1 }  { $1 = leader; print }' inputfile
A aaa
A bbb
A ccc
B ddd
B eee
C fff
```